# php and jquery cannot run through all conditions

Tags: php, jquery

I'm writing a code for my website. in this I use drag-drop to give point.
This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
  $('#id0').ready(function() {
    if ($(this).find('img#e1').length) {
      a = 3;
    } else if ($(this).find('img#e2').length) {
      a = -3;
    } else {
      a = 0
    };
    $.post('php/noname1.php', {
      point: a
    })
  });
});
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","data") ;

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$point=$_POST['point'];
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (point, part, comment) values ($point,'first','good')");

?>
```

When I click on `#click`, the php runs but in the database it only gets 3, even though I've changed the img from `#e1` to `#e2`. I think the problem is in the jQuery code, but I don't see anything wrong in the code. Anybody know ?
Here's the html:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div id='header'><img id='logo' src='photo/prlogo.jpg' width='420' height='120'></div>    
</header>
<div id='body'>
<div id='product'><img id="product" src="photo/pr.jpg" ></div>
<div id='face'>  
    <img id="e1" class='e' src="photo/hap.png"   width="50" height="50"> 
    <img id="e2" class='e' src="photo/sad.png"  width="50" height="50">
</div>   
<button type="button" id='click' >Send</button>
<button type="button" id='undo'>Change your mind ?</button>
</div>
```

and this is how I create #id0, it's a div, droppable, I divided the picture into 5 div, #id0 is one of them:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < d; i++ ) {
        divi.push('<div id="id' + i + '" class="tile" />');

    }
```

Comment: what's that `$('#id0').ready` ?

Comment: I want that #id0 to run the function when i click, or is that just not necessary ?

Comment: please add some HTML. It seems to me that `#id0` will always have img#e1. Cannot do anything without seeing the important bits of html

Comment: please see the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that `#id0` is your *drop zone*

**HTML**

```
<div id='product'><img id="product" src="photo/pr.jpg" ></div>
<div id='face'>
    <img id="e1" class='e' src="photo/hap.png"   width="50" height="50">
    <img id="e2" class='e' src="photo/sad.png"  width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="id0"></div>
<button type="button" id='click'>Send</button>
<button type="button" id='undo'>Change your mind ?</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    if ($('#id0 img#e1').length) {
      a = 3;
    } else if ($('#id0 img#e2').length) {
      a = -3;
    } else {
      a = 0
    };
    console.log(a)
});
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6JQxW/